# Configure a different routesFile for each locale

Tags: angular

Current `project.json` for reference (I use Nx):

```
{
  "name": "public",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "app",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/public/src",
  "tags": ["public"],
  "i18n": {
    "locales": {
      "da": {
        "translation": "apps/public/src/locale/messages.da.json"
      },
      "sv": {
        "translation": "apps/public/src/locale/messages.sv.json"
      }
    }
  },
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "outputs": [
        "{options.outputPath}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/public",
        "index": "apps/public/src/index.html",
        "browser": "apps/public/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "apps/public/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "assets",
            "output": "assets"
          },
          "apps/public/src/favicon.ico",
          "apps/public/src/assets",
          "apps/public/src/site.webmanifest"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "apps/public/src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "styles",
            "libs/stylekit/src/lib"
          ]
        },
        "scripts": [],
        "server": "apps/public/src/main.server.ts",
        "prerender": {
          "discoverRoutes": false,
          "routesFile": "apps/public/prerendered-routes.sv.txt"
        },
        "ssr": false
      },
      "configurations": {
        "da": {
          "baseHref": "/da/",
          "localize": ["da"]
        },
        "sv": {
          "baseHref": "/sv/",
          "localize": ["sv"]
        },
        "production": {
          "localize": ["da", "sv"],
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
          "ssr": false,
          "prerender": false,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "apps/public/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "apps/public/src/environments/environment.development.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "da": {
          "buildTarget": "hub:build:development,da"
        },
        "sv": {
          "buildTarget": "hub:build:development,sv"
        },
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "public:build:production,sv"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "public:build:development,sv"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "public:build"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nx/eslint:lint",
      "outputs": [
        "{options.outputFile}"
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nx/jest:jest",
      "outputs": [
        "{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/public/jest.config.ts"
      }
    },
    "serve-static": {
      "executor": "@nx/web:file-server",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "public:build"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to point to a `prerendered-routes.<locale>.txt` file using the following configuration:

```
"prerender": {
  "discoverRoutes": false,
  "routesFile": "apps/public/prerendered-routes.<locale>.txt"
},
```

However, this has to be done **per-locale** and **not per-project** like it is now:

```
 "targets": {
    "build": {
      ...
      "options": {
        ...
        "prerender": {
          "discoverRoutes": false,
          "routesFile": "apps/public/prerendered-routes.sv.txt"
        },
      }
```

What I'm looking for is something like this for my configured locales:

```
  "i18n": {
    "locales": {
      "da": {
        "translation": "apps/public/src/locale/messages.da.json",
        "prerender": {
          "discoverRoutes": false,
          "routesFile": "apps/public/prerendered-routes.da.txt"
        },
      },
      "sv": {
        "translation": "apps/public/src/locale/messages.sv.json",
        "prerender": {
          "discoverRoutes": false,
          "routesFile": "apps/public/prerendered-routes.sv.txt"
        },
      }
    }
  },
```

or this:

```
"configurations": {
    "da": {
      "baseHref": "/da/",
      "localize": ["da"],
      "prerender": {
        "discoverRoutes": false,
        "routesFile": "apps/public/prerendered-routes.da.txt"
      },
    },
    "sv": {
      "baseHref": "/sv/",
      "localize": ["sv"],
      "prerender": {
        "discoverRoutes": false,
        "routesFile": "apps/public/prerendered-routes.sv.txt"
      },
    },
    "production": {
      "localize": ["da", "sv"],
      ...
    }
```

But none of these are working, and the documentation doesn't mention anything about this.

**So my question is, is this possible, and if so, how?**